# Varnish Cache invalidation after POST request

Tags: post, caching, varnish

I was not able answer on my question. But does `Varnish` invalidate cache of page after `post request`? For example I have page, where user can put his comment, after posting his comment, does `Varnish` purge cache, or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After little chat, on official IRC:
By default, meaning in `builtin.vcl`, cache lookup is bypassed for `POST requests -- return(pass)` from `vcl_recv` so it doesn't change anything in the cache, it just doesn't look in the cache, and the backend response is marked as uncacheable.